# Invalidate Pages when/before Memory Mapping to avoid OS reading from disk

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, windows-7

I'm doing some write-only memory mapping from a process for IPC. However, the problem is that even though I am only writing the OS still reads in the pages that are going to be overwritten from disk which slows down things significantly.

I've tried to simply `std::memset(ptr, 0, view_size)` as soon as I create a new view (`MapViewOfFile`) to hint to the OS not to read in the pages. But I'm guessing either it is reading them in anyway or it is trying to be smart and pre-fetch pages from the disk.

Is there any way I can stop this behaviour? e.g. when you've just created a new file and start writing the OS does not read anything in since the pages are not "valid". Could I maybe "invalidate" pages, similarly to how they are invalidated when added to a new parse file, before creating a mapped view so that the OS doesn't read them in?

Comment: Probably not, except by first truncating the file to zero length.  But since you're doing IPC, can you use a memory mapping backed by the pagefile instead of one backed by a real file?

Comment: What about FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA?

Comment: Not according to the documentation, and if someone used it to explicitly zero a file ahead of time it would be annoying to discover that it had not in fact done so but had instead merely changed the valid data length.  But it might be worth trying.

Comment: Not according to which part of the documentation?

Comment: "equivalent to using the WriteFile function to write zeros (0) to a file" sounds exactly like what I'm looking for? What am I missing?

Comment: The reason a new file works is that the data in the clusters you're mapping is after the valid data length.  That is, the clusters have been allocated but not written to, which typically means they contain random content from previous files.  When Windows is asked to read a cluster that is after the valid data length, it returns zeros instead of actually reading from the disk.

Comment: The documentation on FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA doesn't say that it reduces the valid data length, so my guess is that it doesn't, but behaves as if you'd explicitly written zeros - which may increase the valid data length, but will never reduce it.  (That's because if you're zeroing out the file ahead of time in order to use it for fast random-access writes, you don't want Windows to forget that the data is valid and insist on writing great chunks of it all over again.)

Comment: You might try using a sparse file (FSCTL_SET_SPARSE) because in that case FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA is more likely to work the way you want - although the documentation just says "may not allocate" rather than "will not allocate" which is disconcertingly vague.  Also, it might cause the file to become fragmented, which could be a problem if you're using conventional disk.